# How to remove the last selected event in Fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, flask, fullcalendar, jinja2

If i clicked in a specific date in calendar to make an appointment a modal appears to choose the user, service, date and time and leave comment, the modal has two buttons, first to make the appointment and the second to **cancel the appointment**, the **problem** is if i want to select another date , i see two events, one that i clicked before and the current one, if clicked **make appointment** button the two appointments will be created and i won't that to happen .

Please, how to delete the last clicked event when i click **Cancel button** .

### **Updates:**

**Calendar block**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3 class="page-header text-uppercase">Booking</h3>
          {% if client.is_subscriber(master.id) %}
            <div id="calendar"></div>
          {% else %}
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible alert-disappear" role="alert">
                You have to subscribe first .
            </div>
          {% endif %}
          <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal code that appears on dayClick:

```
<div class="modal_window" id="calendar-modal" style="display: none;">
  <div class="book_block">
    <div class="base_part">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible alert-disappear" role="alert" style="display: none;" id="SuccessAppointment">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          Appointment created.
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible alert-disappear" role="alert" style="display: none;" id="FaildAppointment">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          Error.
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="serviceSet" id="serviceSet">
      <div class="line">
        <span class="line_name">Master:</span>
        <div class="line_input">
          <span>{{master.name}} {{master.family}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="line">
        <span class="line_name">Service:</span>
        <select id="serviceTitleCalendar">
            <option selected>choose service</option>
            <option disabled="disabled">-----</option>
            {% for service in master.services %}
                <option value="{{service.title}}" data-service='{{service.id}}'>{{service.title}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <textarea id="serviceCommentCalendar" cols="60" rows="3" maxlength="160" class="comment" placeholder="Leave a comment" name="commentCalendar"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_part">
      <input id="change-cancel-calendar" type="button" value="Отменить" onclick="$('#calendar-modal').hide();">
      <input type="button" value="make appointment" id="send-appo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Full fullcalendar js code**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var initialLocaleCode = 'ru';
var d = new Date();
var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },

  timezone: 'local',
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  height: 650,
  locale: initialLocaleCode,
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  editable: false,
  resizable: true,
  eventResize: true,
  minTime: "06:00:00",
  maxTime: "22:00:00",
  eventLimit: 6, // allow "more" link when too many events
  select: function(title, start, end, jsEvent, view) {


    var modal = $('#calendar-modal');
    var title = $("select#serviceTitleCalendar option").filter(":selected").val();
    var eventData;

    if (title) {

      $(modal).attr('style', 'display: block');

      $("select#serviceTitleCalendar option").filter(function() {
          return $(this).val() == $("#serviceSet").val();
      }).attr('selected', true);

      $("select#serviceTitleCalendar").on("change", function() {
        $("#serviceSet").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));

        eventData = {
          id: Math.round(Math.random()*100),
          title: $("#serviceSet").val(),
          start: start,
          end: end
        };


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);

        $('#send-appo').on('click', function(){
              eventData = {
                  title: $("#serviceSet").val(),
                  comment: $('#serviceCommentCalendar').val(),
                  start: start,
                  end: end
              };
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/client/cat-{{g.current_directory}}/appointment/calendar',
                  cache: false,
                  data: {
                      'title': eventData['title'],
                      'comment': eventData['comment'],
                      'start': eventData['start']['_d'],
                      'end': eventData['end']['_d']
                  }
              })
              .done(function(data){
                  if(data.error){
                    $('#FaildAppointment').attr('style', 'display: block');
                    $('#SuccessAppointment').attr('style', 'display: none');
                  }
                  else {
                    $(modal).attr('style', 'display: none');
                  }

              });
        });

      });
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
  },
  events: [
    {% for appo in master.appointments %}
      {
        title: "На услуги: \n {{appo.service.title}} \n\n {% if appo.note %} Комментарий: \n{{appo.note}} {% endif %}",
        start: "{{appo.start_time}}",
        end: "{{appo.end_time}}",
        status: '{{appo.is_accepted}}'
      },
    {% endfor %}
  ],
  eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      if(event.status == 'True') {
          element.css('background-color', 'green', 'border-color', 'green');
      } else {
        element.css('background-color', '#e74c3c', 'border-color', '#e74c3c');
      }
  },
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      if(confirm("Really delete event " + calEvent.title + " ?")) {
          // delete event in backend
          jQuery.post(
              "/delete/appointment/"
              , { "id": calEvent.id }
          );
          // delete in frontend
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
      }
  },
  viewRender: function (view,element) {

      if (moment() >= view.start && moment() <= view.end) {
          $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', true); 
          $(".fc-prev-button").addClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
      }
      else {
          $(".fc-prev-button").removeClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
          $(".fc-prev-button").prop('disabled', false); 
      }
  }
});
```

Inside my eventData, i've added a **random id** just to see if i clicked the cancel button all the clicked events get deleted or not, they get deleted completely from the calendar, but they still out there somewhere, i can see them if i confirmed the appointment, i get 4 or 5 notifications inside my dashboard .

In **eventClick**, if i clicked on event directly it asks where if i want to delete it or not, in fact the deletion process should happens when i click the cancel button not after .

Comment: any suggestions guys ??

Comment: Is there any one to not cache the last clicked event ??

Comment: You haven't shown all of the relevant code in fact, but I would guess this is an event-binding problem. Every time the "select" method runs, you add another set of event handlers ("change" event to "serviceTitleCalendar", "click" event to "send-appo"). You can have multiple event handlers attached to an element, so they will keep building up. So then on the second/third/fourth etc selection it might create the event 2/3/4 or more times because 2/3/4 of the same event handlers are running. You need to use "off" to remove the old handlers for each element before re-creating them

Comment: Also you seem to add the event to the calendar as soon as the value of "serviceTitleCalendar" changes. (I don't know what that element is because you haven't shown it). You don't even wait for the ajax call to succeed and save it to the server.  By the time you click the "cancel" button it's already too late, the appointment is in the calendar. I think you should wait to insert it into the calendar until after the user clicks "Make appointment" and the ajax has saved it successfully to the server.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your interest :) , could you please explain in more details !!

Comment: well, what don't you understand from my description? That is quite a lot of detail already.

Comment: @ADyson, well, first of all what do you mean by **need to use 'off'** ??

Comment: The opposite of "on": http://api.jquery.com/off/ it removes existing event handlers from an element. Since your function will re-declare the event handlers each time it runs, you need to remove the previous ones first.

Comment: @ADyson, it still not working, even i gave each event an id , and by clicking **cancel appointment** the button removes any called event by this call `$('calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventData.id, true)`, here each not confirmed event get deleted from the calendar , but by sending the `ajax` request i get them all as a confirmed events !!!!! , also i tried the **off** instead of **on**, please is there any live example showing how to avoid that ??

Comment: Actually I suggested you not to add the event to the calendar until after the ajax, that way user cannot cancel. That would remove the problem you describe. I would move `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);` inside the ajax ".done" function.

Comment: @ADyson, dude , same thing, they get duplicated as far as i clicked on more than one date , all of them are getting sent :( .

Comment: the proof of concept, lets consider that the user clicked on 02/08/2017 and he changed his mind, he click close , then he will choose another date, as am using the code above, he will send all the events that he clicked, thats the problem .

Comment: I think there should be a validation inside `select: function(start, end) { // here }`, for example `if eventData > 1 return false`, i've added a `console.log(eventData)` , inside the console i see more than one eventData list, they are belongs to the clicks that i made , sound weird, isn't ??

Comment: your code still isn't using .`off()` as far as I can see. That's almost certainly why it runs multiple times. I thought I had already explained this. Try writing `$("select#serviceTitleCalendar").off("change"); $("select#serviceTitleCalendar").on("change", function() {...` and `$('#send-appo').off("click"); $('#send-appo').on('click', function(){...` Otherwise, you just keep on adding more and more event handlers to the same elements every time you make a selection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved, as @ADyson mentioned above , that i need to use **.off()** beside with **.on()** to prevent adding more event handlers to the same element , you can do this by just typing :

$(selector).off("change");

OR

$(selector).off("click");

it depends on your code.

Another thing to mention that, i've created an if statement to choose just the picked date from the calendar if the date is valid if not won't choose it, here is the updated `select:` event:

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, allDay, view) {
    if (start.weekday()!=0 && start.weekday()!=6) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select',start);
    }

    events: [

    ],

}
```

also don't forget to add `unselectAuto` and switch it to `false` inside your configurations to avoid automatic unselecting if you canceled the event which in our case as i mentioned above we need to select and unselect just the clicked element.

Another thing i realized why there is more and more events adding by each click is that because i must have deleted the extra **eventData** after `$("#serviceSet").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));` which caused the problem also .

I will work more on that later, but tell know the problem get solved .

Eventually, i'd really want to thank again @ADyson for his interests :)